# Using animated cursor in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

How do I use animated cursor "myCrusor.ani" in C# winform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-how-to-use-custom-cursors